# How to implement a progress bar in JSP?

Tags: jsp, progress-bar

I am trying to mock a progress bar on my jsp. I have included a gif file in div tag which is not displayed when page loads initially.

I want to show the gif file when user submits the page. On submit huge database activities run in background.

The problem that I am facing the the gif file loses its animation affect.

Please help me out.

```
<div id="progress" style="display: none">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">Please do not refresh or hit
        back button while processing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">Please wait while importing....</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><IMG
        SRC="${outputBean.contextRoot}/images/greenLoader.gif" WIDTH="265"
            HEIGHT="15" BORDER="0" ALT="" id="progress"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser do you use? This just works fine in Opera 9.64, IE6, FF 3.0.11. I did set display="block" with javascript and the gifs was running fine

Comment: Is it an endless gif? Or does it only run for a certain amount of iterations

Comment: I am using endless gif on IE 6

Comment: This is not a progress bar, it's just a "please wait" animation. You cannot see how much progress the database has made by looking at it.